What is a backend and frontend node id in Chrome DevTools protocol?
The Chrome DevTools documentation mentions backend and frontend node IDs. What's frontend in the DevTools world and what are backend and frontend node IDs? What does it mean to push a backend node to a frontend?

@TylerH, it's a specific question about CDP, your comment doesn't apply.

@wOxxOm Nothing in my comment is invalidated by that fact. The question is still too broad and has answers to most if not all of the questions asked here already.

Every topic you found is irrelevant to the question. This question is about a specific feature of CDP.  All those "multiple things" have a short single answer judging by the source code of CDP, i.e. it's not a broad question, but I want to wait for someone from devtools team, just in case.

AFAICT, pushing means that CDP's backend finds a DOM node by its backend id (or tree path) and fires DOM.setChildNodes that provides devtools UI frontend with the info about the node and optionally its children.
